# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array laravel

Tags: php, laravel, crud, one-to-one

I'm trying to post an image from a one to many relationship while also doing the CRUD (create part), but I am having some trouble doing it. I keep on getting this error`,Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array`, whenever I try to use associate to define the relationship together with user_info with user_image table. So what should I do?

Here are my codes:
createController:

```
public function create1(){

    return view('create1');
}

public function store1(Request $request){
     $this->validate($request, [
        'input_img' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

 $user_info = Session::get('data');
      $UserImage = new UserImage($request->input()) ;


     if($file = $request->hasFile('input_img')) {
      $file = array();



        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName() ;
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/images' ;
        $file->move($destinationPath,$fileName);
        $UserImage->userImage = $fileName ;
        $UserImage = UserImage::create(['file' => $request->file('input_img')]);
        $UserImage->user_infos()->associate($user_info);
    }

    $UserImage->save() ;

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

HomeController(this is where I print out my information)

```
public function getInfo($id) {

  $data = personal_info::where('id',$id)->get();
      $data3=UserImage::where('user_id',$id)->get();
 return view('test',compact('data','data3'));
```

blade.php (how I show the image in view)

```
 @foreach ($data3 as $object9)
 <img width="100" height="100" src="{!! $object9->signature !!}">
    @endforeach
```

UserImage model(in table I used binary format to store in DB)

```
    class UserImage extends Eloquent
    {
            protected $fillable = array('userImage','user_id');
        public function user_infos() {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\user_info', 'user_id', 'id');
        }

class user_info extends Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = array('Email', 'Name');
    protected $table = user_infos';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
        public function UserImages() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserImage','user_id');
    }
}
```

create1.blade.php(this is how I upload the image)

```
     <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/userUpload')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        {{  csrf_field()  }}


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="imageInput" class="control-label col-sm-3">Upload Image</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input data-preview="#preview" name="input_img" type="file" id="imageInput">
            <img class="col-sm-6" id="preview"  src="" ></img>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6-offset-2">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
            </div>
          </div>
          </form>
```

Comment: On which line of which file are you getting the error?

Comment: I'm getting it on this line "$fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName() ;"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a problem inside `store1()` method. You sould not re-declare  `$file`.

```
if($file = $request->hasFile('input_img')) {

    $file = array();

    $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
```

Instead get the file using the `file()` method:

```
if($request->hasFile('input_img')) {

    $file = $request->file('input_img');

    $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
```

See more on the [Laravel's requests documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files).

Comment: Hi Camilo, tks for the reply, I am now getting this error instead, "Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on boolean", any idea?

Comment: Yes, you need to grab the uploaded file calling `$request->input_img` or `$request->file('input_img')`. Updating my answer.

Comment: Hi, Camilo your answer worked !! tks a lot but suddenly it couldn't be saved into database

Comment: That's because your trying to store the file itself into the database. A common practice it's to only store the file name.

Comment: But I want to retrieve it and show it in my blade.php based on the user_id of the relationship between user_info and userImage table. Example, Jack (id =1 from user_info) must link back with Image(user_id=1 from userImage). Or is there another way instead of doing in the database itself

Comment: I recommend you searching for that specific problem on the web or creating a new question for it. Please, if my response answered your question consider accepting it.

Comment: Ok, tks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Read through your logic in the `store1` method again... You are setting the `$file` variable to an empty array and then trying to call the `getClientOriginalName()` method on it:

```
$file = array();

$fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this in laravel 9

```
$allFile =count($request->files);

for($i=0; $i<$allFile; $i++){
dd($request->files[$i].getClientOriginalName());

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).